Why won't my Javascript audio skip button work?
I am fairly new to any sort of web programming and trying to create an audio player for my website. I'll paste all the code below for reference. I cannot for the life of me get the skip button to work. I have two files in the right spot that both should work for the audio element, and the first is the one already loaded on the site (it is playing/pausing fine). But I can't figure out why the forward button won't work on click. I tried two ways of creating the function, one will be pasted here and the other was just using the onclick="" attribute in HTML that linked to a function in JS. Any insight would be greatly appreciated! Also, I am anticipating having to add a clause for if the song is the last on the list, but I haven't gotten that far yet.
<div class="window" id="audioPlayer">
<div class="windowHeader" id="audioPlayerHeader"><span class="windowCloseButton" id="closeAudioPlayer">X</span>==== Audio Player ====</div>

<div class='marqueeContainer'><div class="marquee">Choir Singing - The Choir</div><div class="marquee">Choir Singing - The Choir</div></div>

<audio src="../assets/choir.mp3" muted loop id="audio1"></audio>

<div id="buttonBar">
<img src="../assets/back.png" id='backButton' onclick="backAudio(audio1)">
<img src="../assets/playButton.png" id="audio1PlayButton" onclick="toggleAudioPlay('../assets/pauseButton.png', '../assets/playButton.png', 'audio1')">
<img src="../assets/forward.png" id="forwardButton"></div>
</div>

const songSrcs = new Array("../assets/choir.mp3", "../assets/piano.mp3");
const songMap = new Map();
songMap.set("../assets/choir.mp3", "Choir Singing - The Choir");
songMap.set("../assets/piano.mp3", "Piano that Plays");
let audioElement = document.getElementById(audio1);

var forwardButton = document.getElementById("forwardButton");
forwardButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let currentTrack = audioElement.src;
    let currentPos = songSrcs.indexOf(currentTrack);
    currentPos++;
    currentTrack = songSrcs[currentPos];
    document.getElementById("audio1").src = currentTrack;
    document.querySelectorAll(".marquee").innerHTML = songMap.value(currentTrack);
})


let audioElement = document.getElementById(audio1); that is the mistake - audio1 needs to be "audio1" - I'm surprised you didn't mention any errors in the browser developer tools console

@JaromandaX I can't believe I missed that! Rewrote the code late last night and it must've slipped my mind. I did just run it again with the fixed .getElementById and it is still not working...I feel like I've tried every possible solution and it never functions. Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated!

In the OP the callback functions,  onclick="backAudio(audio1)" and onclick="toggleAudioPlay()" are missing. After seeing that I knew it'd be a waste of time correcting it, there's just too many syntactical errors and missing pieces. The example below addresses all of your problems (at least all of the problems as I tried to understand from your explanation ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ). Details are commented in the code.


// Always declare counters outside of functions
let index = 0;
// This is the URL where all of the gif/png and mp3s are located
const base = "https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/";
// Array of mp3s
const mp3s = ["mp3/righteous.mp3", "mp3/jerky.mp3", "mp3/nosegoblin.mp3"];
// Array of images
const imgs = ["img/link.gif", "img/sol.png", "img/ren.gif"];
// 2 array of strings
const artists = ["Samuel L. Jackson", "Sol Rosenberg", "Ren"];
const titles = ["Righteous", "Whatnot", "Magic Nose Goblins"];

// This an Audio object. It is like an <audio> but without the <audio>
const player = new Audio();
// References to:
// <img>
const image = document.querySelector(".image");
// <figcaption> (it's the scrolling part of the .marquee)
const scroll = document.querySelector(".scroll");
// all <button> and <fieldset>
const io = document.forms.ui.elements;
// <output>
const count = io.count;
// <button>
const play = io.play;
// <button>
const prev = io.prev;
// <button>
const next = io.next;

/** 
 * Callback bound to play <button>
 * Plays/pauses currently loaded MP3
 */
function onPlay(e) {
  if (player.paused || player.ended) {
    if (!player.src) {
      loadSrc();
      return;
    }
    this.classList.add("pause");
    player.play();
  } else {
    this.classList.remove("pause");
    player.pause();
  }
}

/**
 * Callback bound to prev/next <button>s
 * Plays either previous or next MP3
 */
function onSkip(e) {
  /** 
   * This expression returns -1 if the user clicked the prev <button>
   * otherwise it'll return a 1
   */
  let dir = this.id === "prev" ? -1 : 1;
  // This changes the index by -1 or +1
  index = index + dir;
  /** 
   * If index is equal or greater than the length of the mp3s array...
   *   return 0 (reset the count to the beginning)
   * If index is less than zer0...
   *   return the length of array mp3s - 1 (reser the count to the end)
   *   otherwise just use the index unchanged
   */
  index = index >= mp3s.length ?
    0 :
    index < 0 ?
    mp3s.length - 1 :
    index;
  loadSrc();
}

/**
 * This will display the count (index +1)
 * Load the new IMG
 * Render the text on the scroller
 * Change the play <button> icon
 * Load the MP3
 * Play the MP3
 */
function loadSrc() {
  count.value = index + 1;
  image.src = base + imgs[index];
  scroll.textContent = artists[index] + " - " + titles[index];
  play.classList.add("pause");
  player.src = base + mp3s[index];
  player.play();
}

/** 
 * All of the event handlers, one for each <button>
 * The last one will change the icon on the play <button> when the player 
 * is no longer playing.
 */
play.onclick = onPlay;
prev.onclick = onSkip;
next.onclick = onSkip;
player.onended = e => play.classList.remove("pause");
:root {
  5vmax/1.5 "Segoe UI";
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1.0);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 90vh;
  margin: 10vh auto;
}

.panel {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: fit-content;
  border: 0;
}

.box {
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.marquee {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 90vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px -4px lightblue;
}

#count {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: Consolas;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 1.0);
}

.image {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

.scroll {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 50vw;
  height: 3ex;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  text-align: right;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 1.0);
  animation: rightToLeft 7s backwards linear infinite;
}

.buttons {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 33%;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
  transition: 0.3s;
  box-shadow: rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.3) 0px 1px 2px 0px, rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.15) 0px 2px 6px 2px;
}

button:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 1.0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:active {
  color: rgba(0, 127, 255, 1.0);
  transform: translateY(1px);
}

#prev {
  border-right: 1px inset rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
}

#play {
  border-left: 1px inset rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-right: 1px inset rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#play::before {
  content: "⯈";
}

#play.pause::before {
  content: "❚❚";
}

#next {
  border-left: 1px inset rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
}

@keyframes rightToLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(200%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
<main>
  <form id="ui">
    <fieldset name="panel" class="panel box">
      <figure class="marquee">
        <output id="count"></output>
        <img class="image" src="https://i.ibb.co/0VRWJqQ/mp3poster.png">
        <figcaption class="scroll"></figcaption>
      </figure>
      <fieldset name="panel" class="panel buttons">
        <button id="prev" type="button"></button>
        <button id="play" type="button"></button>
        <button id="next" type="button"></button>
      </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</main>



